# Is it possible to make 2 different POST requests to the same endpoint consecutively with Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

So I want to make a POST request to send a,b,c values to the server get a response and then make another POST request to send d,e,f values this time.

```
@POST("getRequest")
    Call<InitPost> postInit(@Body InitPost initPost); //to send "a", "b", "c"

    @POST("getRequest")
    Call<InitPostOk> postInitOk(@Body InitPostOk initPostOk); //to send "d","e","f"
```

Their POJO's are different but the endpoints are the same. Is it possible to do this? There is no issue in the first request.

Comment: This can be possible using Rxjava 2 flatMap operator.please look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RxJava`'s `Observable.concat()`

```
Observable.concat(yourReftrofitService.postInit(req1), yourReftrofitService.postInitOk(req2))
```

Along with changing your retrofit service to (note use of `Observable`):

```
@POST("getRequest")
Observable<InitPost> postInit(@Body InitPost initPost); 

@POST("getRequest")
Observable<InitPostOk> postInitOk(@Body InitPostOk initPostOk);
```

An alternative, as @Pankaj mentioned, is to use `flatMap` ...this is particularly useful if you want to use result of request 1 in request 2.